# Android Appium : Not able enter the text in textbox

Tags: android, selenium, appium, ui-automation, page-factory

//For log in scenario, I just want to enter the userID and password. I tried with different Xpath but still it's not able to identify the box. every-time getting an no such element exception. We are using testNG.[image]

---

```
@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "XYZ")
public MobileElement txtUserName;
```

---

```
utils.EnterText(UserNameorMailId,txtUserName);
```

---

---

Different Xpath tried: xyz is placeholder.

```
 //*[@id='username'] 
//*[@text='Edit Text  ;  Email Address or Username']
//*[@id='layout_usename']//*[@text='Edit Text  ;  Email Address or Username']
```

Error message:

```
Method threw 'org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException' exception. Cannot evaluate io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$34efbdcd.toString()
```

I am not sure what else I should try and what exactly the issue is...Help is really appreciated ..

Comment: Try the following xpath: `//*[contains(@class, 'Edit')]`

Comment: tried with the given xpath but still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

What's the exact error you are getting while entering text ? In case you are able to find the element Can you try to use ".//*[@text='Email Address or Username']"

Comment: I replaced the given xpath but still getting the same error....   Method threw 'org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException' exception. Cannot evaluate io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$34efbdcd.toString()

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `AndroidElement` instead of `MobileElement`?
From the docs, I can see that `MobileElement` is an abstract class which is inherited by `AndroidElement` class, so using an object of an Abstract class may not work.

MobileElement:
https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/MobileElement.html

AndroidElement:
https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidElement.html

Comment: Tried using the AndroidElement , but still not working. Got the same exception again.

Answer (score 0):

Does clicking on the textbox produce the same error? Have you try setValue instead?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more.. I am not getting you. I am not able to get the textbox WebElement, hence not able to click on it.

Comment: @SacTan setValue is similar to sendkey but if the error is still nosuchelement this may not work. I can think of either the xpath is still incorrect or may need to try other explicit waits like isvisible. One way is in the appium inspector you can find the absolute xpath. You can try using the absolute to see if it works first- if it does not then the issue may be somewhere else (beside xpath).